# Problema na importação de fontes CSS

Tags: css3, css-font-face

Galera, estou com um pequeno problema na importação de fontes, quando coloco as fontes nativas funciona, com excessão da Helvetica, e quando vou importar uma fonte local ou por url é como se não conseguisse acessar a fonte e então o browser usa a default.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Futura';
  src: local('../../../css/font/Futura/Futura.ttc'), url('http://www.projetogiulia.com.br/assets/css/font/Futura/Futura.ttc') !important;
}
```

Há algo de errado com meu código?

Desde já agradeço

Comment: no lugar de `local` coloque `url` e remova o `url` com o link. (removendo o important também)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta importar e depois adicionar, assim:

```
@import url('http://www.projetogiulia.com.br/assets/css/font/Futura/Futura.ttc');
font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
```

outra forma seria em vez de usar o **import url** usar um link

```
<link href="http://www.projetogiulia.com.br/assets/css/font/Futura/Futura.ttc" rel="stylesheet">
```